# Circle CI artifacts endpoint wont accept token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, circleci

**Hi guys - Super Quick TL;DR version:**

My Circle CI endpoint to return artifacts in a JSON contains a first entry, That entry has a URL to a code-coverage JSON file. 
*That* is the data that i need returned via my `axios`, `ajax` or `fetch` API. 
I've tried all three. 
On Postman, via webserver or in the browser console... they all come back with "Not Logged In" sort of errors.

So this is an issue with tokens, access etc I guess?

[ Another person experiencing the same issue - https://discuss.circleci.com/t/circle-token-param-ignored-when-using-api-url-to-fetch-latest-artifact/3197 ]

Has anyone managed to resolve this yet?

Can anyone advise *how* I can get that data (not just the artifacts) returned if Circle CI's endpoint *only* works in the browser? And if the URL for that one-level-deeper sort of information doesn't accept tokens?

Ummmm. Help?

Inside The React Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/ORG/REPO/Latest/artifacts?circle-token=<My TOKEN>")
      .then(function(result){
        console.log('API result===>', result);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of artifact URLs are you using? You should be using the `*.circle-artifacts.com/*` type URLs.

The endpoint you provided in your question should work fine as long as you lowercase `Lower`. It should look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/<org>/<repo>/latest/artifacts?circle-token=<my-token>")
      .then(function(result){
        console.log('API result===>', result);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Hi @FelicianoTech - i've tried both that URL and a `circle-artifacts.com` one.
Neither of them (while in code/web server) will return anything other than "Not Logged In". 

So as i say... i think this is a token issue.

Comment: To be clear: 

*Inside a ComponentDidMount*:

`https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/<org>/<repo>/latest/artifacts?circle-token=<my-token>` - returns "Not Logged In" in browser console.
`https://1244-67429425-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/ubuntu/<projectname>/<report>/json/coverage-final.json` - returns 400 bad request


As an HTTP/URL in Chrome:
either circle-artifacts.com or the normal circleCI URL return all the json i want in the web page (because i'm logged into circle) 

Any ideas?

Comment: For the sake of trying, can you create a new artifacts or a new admin token and try it? If that doesn't work, at this point I'd suggest contacting CircleCI Support.